# Computing confidence interval of average output from random forest in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am computing confidence intervals for random forests using the package available here: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/forest-confidence-interval/auto_examples/plot_mpg.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-mpg-py

I want to plot the average MPG and associated confidence interval. I can compute the average MPG but how do I compute the associated confidence interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link that you post there is a portion that describes how to compute and plot errorbars. These bars are the confidence intervals. If you prefer to have this plotted as bands you could follow [this example](http://blog.datadive.net/prediction-intervals-for-random-forests/)